# Are such functions Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $\mathcal{M}_f(\mathbb{N})$ the space of finite measures on $\mathbb{N}$, ie $\mu = \sum_i a_i \delta_i$ with $a_i\in \mathbb{N}, \sum_i a_i = M < \infty$. Let $\mathcal{M}_1(\mathbb{N})$ be the space of probability measures on $\mathbb{N}$. I'm considering the following functionals :
\begin{align*}
  F \colon \mathcal{M}_f(\mathbb{N}) &\to \mathcal{M}_1(\mathbb{N})\\
  \mu &\mapsto F(\mu):= \sum_i F_i(\mu)\delta_i
\end{align*}
Again $F_i>0$, $\sum F_i = 1$. And we add the condition that for any subset $A$ of $N$ $F(\mu)(A) = 0 \iff \mu(A) = 0$.

My question is the following : Is there a metric subspace $(S,d_S)$ of $ \mathcal{M}_f(\mathbb{N}) $ and again a metric subspace $(S',d_{S'})$ of $\mathcal{M}_1(\mathbb{N})$ such that the restriction of $F$ over $S$ is lipschitz over $S'$ that is:

\begin{equation}
d_{S'}(F(\mu),F(\nu)) \leq  C d_{S}(\mu,\nu)
\end{equation}
What I am asking is: *Do I need to add supplementary restrictions of $\mu$ and $F(\cdot)$ for $F$ to be lipschitz?*

Any suggestions/ideas would be welcome.

**Context**: I have been working on a measure valued EDO where a term popped up with $F$ defined like. I am trying to figure out uniqueness conditions for the solutions so I need $F$ to be somehow Lipschitz. It to be working without any further restrictions when $\mu$ is square integrable ($\sum i^2 a_i < \infty$),  but I don't know how to approach the proof. I've tried the hands on, calculatory approach but it hasnt worked so far...

Comment: What is $F_i$? Are these constants? Then your map is the constant map and obviously Lipschitz.

Comment: I have edited. Sadly those are not constant. $F_i$ can be seen as a way to move the weight on $\mu$

Comment: The condition $Fμ(A)=0\iff μ(A)=0$ seems redundant since both are equivalent to $A=\varnothing$ given that $F_i>0$ and $a_i>0$.

Comment: My God, there was a typo the $a_i$ can be zero...

Comment: What are $d_S$ and $d_{S'}$? If they are arbitrary metrics, you could just choose both to be the discrete metric. Then, any function is $1$-Lipschitz.